# Launch MAP in Xamarin Forms ANDROID and camera move to user's current location

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

all right?

I'm banging my head with something that might be simple, but I can't think of anything else.

I want to make it so that when the user opens my app's map screen, the map camera will focus on where the user is located in real time.

PS: I'm using Xamarin.Essentials

**Ps2: With this code the camera stays at Rome city or moves to ocean, but i need that moves to my atual position.**

Below is the code I'm using, any help is welcome.

```
public async void AproximaLocalUsuario()
        {

            try
            {
                var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
               

                if (location != null)
                {
                    Position position = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);

                    MapSpan mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromKilometers(0.444));
                    map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
                }


            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                // Handle not supported on device exception
            }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: With this code the camera moves to ocean, but i need that moves to my atual position.

Comment: are you using the emulator or an actual device?  Are you requesting location permissions?  Have you checked the value returned by `GetLocationAsync`?

Comment: I'm using actual device. Yes, I have anabled all permissions. How can i check GetLocationAsync value? Can u help me? I think GetLocationAsync don't do nothing.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Or just write to the console log.  Note that with new versions of Android you have to request permissions at runtime, not just "enable" them in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, I wasn't starting the function, that was the problem. Below is the code that is working for me. Thanks for your help and I hope this post helps more people.

[image]